# Can malware take files from USB hard drive

Tags: windows-7, malware

If plug an USB pendirve into an infected computer, can the malware make copies of the files and take the content inside?

I guess it can.

Comment: Yes it can but there are some things which may affect the yes/no answer (what OS, what settings etc). Is that really your question?

Comment: yes. windows 7 os

Comment: Yes; Malware designed for Windows, can do anything the user which launched the process can do, including access your USB hdd.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer is infected with malware, it can usually access all files:

- on that computer,
- on connected network drives,
- on connected external HDD, USB pendrives etc.

Yes